# A simple example of a base point of a linear series

Tags: algebraic-geometry, examples-counterexamples, algebraic-curves

I'm reading [Fulton's algebraic curves book](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf) and he make the following definition of linear series (page 110):

> Let $D$ be a divisor, and let $V$ be a subspace of $L(D)$ (as a vector
>   space). The set of effective divisors $\{div(f)+D\mid f\in V,f\neq
>  0\}$ is called a linear series.

Now we can define base points: We say a point is a base point of a linear series $S$ if there is a point in the curve such that For every divisor $D\in S$ we have $P\in S$.

I'm looking for a simple example of a base point of a linear series. 
So, my question is this set $\{P\}$ can be considered as a linear series? if yes, we can say that $P$ is a base point of $\{P\}$.

Thanks

Comment: For every divisor $D \in S$ we have $P \in D$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already defined, a linear series is a set of linearly equivalent divisors. So a set $\{P\}$ with just one point is indeed a linear series having $P$ as a base point.

Comment: Every linear series is associated with a subspace $V\subset L(D)$. So in the case of the linear system $S=\{P\}$, which $V$ and $L(D)$ can we associate to the linear series $S$?

Comment: $D = P$, namely the divisor has degree one. $V \subset L(D)$ contains the constant functions. So $V$ is a vector subspace of dimension one.

Comment: you are welcome.